# Mojave 10.14.6 is it possible to specific folder icons links in the finder context menu?

Tags: macos, finder, software-recommendation, automation, contextual-menu

Being a 25 plus year daily Mac user I should be able to figure this out, but I'm lost. I'd like to create a clickable folder link in the context menu - hovering over it to see the contents if said folder would be a bonus. Specifically I want the context menu to show items stored on the desktop, but other folder/location links would be great too. The old Finder Pop utility did this well, but won’t run on newer OS.

Can this be set up on macOS Mojave?

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite understand what you want. Do you want to navigate through a folder's contents using the Contextual menu, or simply open a new window to a specific folder, from a contextual menu command... or something else? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve -- as there may be another method which works better/more easily. Aside from programming Finder Extensions, you're limited to Quick Actions created in Shortcuts or Automator.

Comment: " or simply open a new window to a specific folder, from a contextual menu command."
Yes - that's precisely what I want to do - preferably with a text link/command like "desktop", "applications", "home" etc...any ideas on how to accomplish this? There were a number of applications pre Mojave that allowed one to easily modify the Mac contextual menu in this way. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I am sorry, but is that not exactly what the sidebar does? You drag the folders you use the most, in or out of the bar. And they are just one click away...

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy enough to create an Automator workflow that just opens a specific folder in a new window. Save it as a Service, and it will appear in Contextual menus.

There's an Automator action "Reveal Finder Items" that will do this. You would need to use "Get Specified Finder Items" before it, to select the location you want in each Service. Then just save each Service as the name of the location it opens.

However, the point of a contextual menu, as the name suggests, is that the items in the menu relate to the object being right-clicked on, rather than being 'general'.

In the Finder, you can access the Desktop, Applications folder, Home, etc from the Go menu, or with the keyboard shortcuts shown there, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> for Desktop, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> for Applications; <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> for Home...

Alternatively, there are apps like Devontech's [Xmenu](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) utility, which allows for navigable file hierarchies from the menubar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@benwiggy - thanks for the thoughtful and helpful response - I have Xmenu installed and will probably begin to train myself to use it...it does precisely what I'm want, just not in the Mac OS context menus. For some reason, I've never availed myself of the "Go" menu very much for navigation, over the years.
The keyboard shortcuts are great and really what I should be using.
Maybe it's nostalgia and old habits, but there a few things that I just prefer using the mouse to accomplish...
Btw: As of 10.14.6, Apple has done away with the "Service" option when opening a new document in Automator - it's now "Quick Action", and there's no "Save As" (a Service) menu item. Using your suggestion, I created a Quick Action which appears (albeit as a sub menu link) in the finder context menu, but only when control clicking on a **folder**. Which led me to narrow down what my original question should have been - "is there a way to modify and add a clickable location link (desktop etc) to the finder's **Desktop** context menu?" That was it. Perhaps there's an action in Automator to accomplish this, and I'll poke around.
The preference pane FinderPop that ceased to be supported in High Sierra  was really an elegant solution and hack for ALL finder context menus - super easy to congigure etc...old habits ;o

[image]
[image: FinerPop]

Comment: Quick Actions and Services are broadly interchangeable and mostly are the same thing, with some duplication.

Comment: Wow you even use old skins

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t find a utility that works as expected, the next best thing it to bring these recents / automation to the open and save dialogs.

The long time champion for this is [Default Folder X](https://stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/). It :

- Tracks recently used files in every app
- Reopens recently closed Finder windows

It has many, many features but the two above give excellent results and don’t need a lot of training / change in process to benefit from immediately.