# Is it possible to create a Services or Quick Actions item in a blank Finder window?

Tags: macos, finder, automator, filesystem, automation

I have an Automator script that appears in my **Finder>Services** menu (it creates a new file). It works fine with the allocated keyboard shortcut.

When I right-click in an **empty space inside a folder** there’s the Finder’s "New Folder" item (of course) but OS X doesn't seem to offer a *Services* or *Quick Actions* contextual menu that has the "current folder" context unless you actually select a folder.

I’d like my script to **appear in a contextual menu** when right-clicking an empty space in an open folder—is this possible?

Comment: [You’re not alone in wanting automation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/440074/) a folder (especially desktop folder) to behave this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you’ll need to launch the script from key shortcuts or siri

- https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/

I’d start with fast scripts or revisit the end goal and see if something like an Elgato stream deck or X-keys programmable keyboard to launch your automations.

Answer (score 1):

I have been messing around with this myself. I haven't found a way to run a shortcut by right-clicking the empty space; however, if you show the Path bar in your Finder window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), have the **Use as Quick Action** and **Services Menu** checked in Shortcut Details, then in the Path bar, you can right click on the folder where you want the new file then click **Services** > *name of your shortcut* to run your script(s).

Comment: that’s a great tip - thanks. Just had to change the workflow script to receive the current "folders" in the drop-down at the top. It’s now appearing along with my other "clean zip" workflow. I set up a keyboard shortcut for it anyway, which is a bit quicker too.